# Can a Syrian citizen get a US visa? (regarding the travel ban)

Tags: visas, usa, syrian-citizens

My husband and I are looking forward to visit the states. My husband is Jordanian and I’m Syrian. Can I apply to go with him to the U.S?

Comment: Forgot to mention that we are both currently living in Qatar and we have a residency here.

Comment: Why would you like to visit the US?

Comment: @AzorAhai What is the relevance of your question?

Comment: @Musonius Well, is one of them studying? Is one of them on a business trip? It sounds like it's just a pleasure trip but it's hard to tell for sure. It matters because it would affect what visa they need

Comment: @AzorAhai Regardless of the type of visa, the answer is yes.

Comment: Do you have any citizenships apart from the ones you mention?

Comment: @MusoniusRufus Yes, but a good answer will be more than "yes." I don't know anything about applying for US visas, so I was just hoping that Reham would add some more info so they can get the best answer.

Answer (score 15):

Unfortunately, no.

The current [US travel ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_travel_ban) against citizens of Syria and several other countries was generally laid out in [presidential proclamation 9645](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/presidential-proclamation-enhancing-vetting-capabilities-processes-detecting-attempted-entry-united-states-terrorists-public-safety-threats/) issued Sept. 24, 2017, and [upheld by the Supreme Court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trump_v._Hawaii) on June 26, 2018, despite [significant controversy within the US](https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation-now/2018/06/26/supreme-court-travel-ban-ruling-americans-react-verdict/734995002/). The rules are different for citizens of each affected country.

Under [the current rules](https://www.sggimmigration.com/navigating-the-trump-travel-ban-frequently-asked-questions/), Syrian citizens are banned from obtaining a US visa and traveling to the US unless they fit one of the [exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executive_Order_13780#Section_3:_Scope_and_implementation_of_the_suspension).   The most common exceptions are:

- If you already have a US visa, US permanent residency, asylum, or advance parole, it remains valid and you can travel to the US.
- If you have dual citizenship, you could still get a US visa and travel to the US using your non-Syrian passport.
- If you have existing close ties with the US, you can apply for a case-by-case waiver.  If you're unsure whether you qualify for this, you could contact your local US consulate to ask.

If you don't qualify for an exception or a case-by-case waiver, you would be unable to get a US visa.

Comment: The page you link to says you need a document *other than a visa* that permits travel to the US?

Comment: @jpatokal that's section 3(b)(iii). It's only one of several exceptions. The page doesn't talk much about section 3(a), which defines the scope of the order so as not to invalidate visas that were issued before the order took effect.

Comment: @jpatokal In addition to what phoog said, the Wikipedia page I linked isn't as clear as it could be. I just linked [this page](https://www.sggimmigration.com/navigating-the-trump-travel-ban-frequently-asked-questions/) that is clearer about the current rules.

Answer (score 10):

Well, I am a Syrian myself and I have applied for the US visa earlier this year (2019) and was granted a 3 months visa. My plan is to visit the US during summer vacation so the officer approved my visa and asked me to mail my passport a week before my planned flight to get it on.

My condition is as follows:
I live in Turkey.
Homemaker.
No other passport.
Good travel history.
Valid Canadian visa.
Travelling with my Egyptian husband.
I have visited the US before on 2016.

What the officer was most focused on was my previous visit to the US, and somehow my Canadian visa.

So in short, it's not impossible to obtain US visa for Syrians. But definitely it's not a piece of cake.

Good Luck.

Comment: *to mail my passport a week before my planned flight* -- this is a bit unusual, but might be explained by the timing of only 3 months validity. I hope it goes smoothly. Please let us know how it works out.