# I'm Syrian Citizen and i want to go to USA

Tags: visas, usa

My Sister is already in the USA and she has a green card. She has a baby that is born in US so he is an American citizen. My question is, can I get a visa to visit  her and her son?

**note : i applied for a visit visa before she had a green card and baby so I got
refused**

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Syrian citizen get a US visa? (regarding the travel ban)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122503/can-a-syrian-citizen-get-a-us-visa-regarding-the-travel-ban). It doesn't matter the baby is USA citizen. Even if your sister were a US citizen (and that requires five years residency until she can file, roughly another to get it) then she could file an I-130 to petiion you to immigrate but the processing time for that for siblings is ten years. Rather, organize a vacation in a third country.

Comment: she not only has a baby she get a green card but when i get refused she was a visitor

Comment: Her green card doesn't matter anymore than her baby. - And no matter how many people you know and what their status is, if *you* apply for a visa, *you* still have to fulfill the requirements.

Comment: @Henrik Actually, arguably, her green card makes it even harder for OP to visit because the risk OP is going to overstay indefinitely increases when staying with a resident.

Answer (score 6):

If you were refused a visitor visa previously, then the fact that your sister has since had a baby will not change the reasons for the refusal. You will need to address the reasons for why *you* were refused a visa.

Comment: they actually said that because i'm SYRIAN citizen but the employee told me that i can re-applied again without my father because he just screamed on me in the embassy and she not only has a baby she get a green card but when i get refused she was a visitor

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, the current travel ban will prevent you from getting a visa for the reason of your citizenship.

Comment: comment edited sorry for late :(

Comment: so what i have to do what the mistake that i do if i'm a syrian citizen it's not my fault

Comment: @user96671 unfortunately for you, US law says that Syrian citizens are generally unable to get US visas.  It is not fair, but that is not enough for a legal challenge.  There is a waiver available, but the last I heard (several months ago), it seems that these waivers are essentially impossible to get in practice.  Your sister could try asking the office of her congressional representative or one of her senators for help.  Alternatively, and more expensively, she could try asking an immigration lawyer on your behalf whether anything can be done.

Answer (score 6):

You won't be able to get to the USA to visit your sister; but you may be able to visit Canada or Mexico and meet there.  This is easier for several reasons:

- Canada and Mexico do not have a visa ban for Syrian nationals;
- In Canada and Mexico you would not be visiting someone who already lives there; remember you have to convince the visa officer that you are not intending to immigrate.  It will be easier to convince the officer thereof if you're not visiting your family at their home;
- Possibly, Canadian or Mexican border control is less strict in general (I'm not sure if this is true).

A friend of mine (UK citizen) meets their spouse (US citizen) typically in Ireland, because if they were to meet in the UK or the US it would be harder to convince the officer they're not intending to permanently stay with their spouse.