# H1B US Visa for Syrian

Tags: visas, usa, syrian-citizens

I am a syrian citizen. I am a PhD holder from the UK and currently a professor in a college in Oman. I recently got a contract to work in a state university in California. The university is currently working on my petition (H1B). I need to apply for a US visa in the next couple of weeks. Does the ban against Syrians to enter the US affect my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not an immigration lawyer and you or your employer should seek legal advice, but it does appear that the so-called Travel Ban 3.0 would block all Syrian citizens from coming to the USA on either immigrant or non-immigrant visas: https://www.acslaw.org/expertforum/trumps-travel-ban-two-years-later/

You may also want to look at this answer which details some loopholes (and the respondent to the second answer says they got a visa): [Can a Syrian citizen get a US visa? (regarding the travel ban)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122503/can-a-syrian-citizen-get-a-us-visa-regarding-the-travel-ban)

Again, seek professional legal advice rather than internet strangers.