# Can a German-Syrian dual citizen obtain US humanitarian parole?

Tags: dual-nationality, syrian-citizens

If a person has German and Syrian citizenship, can they get humanitarian parole to enter the US, despite the travel ban for Syrian citizens? I applied for a B1/B2 tourist visa with my German passport and have been waiting for seven months for application processing. My need to travel is urgent. I want to visit a seriously ill relative who lives in the US.

---

Here's an update: My relative's senator is working on the issue, and the word is that we're waiting for security clearance from Washington.

Comment: Are you in the US? [Advance parole](https://www.cbp.gov/travel/us-citizens/advance-parole) is for people who are in the US waiting for an immigration status adjustment and need to travel outside the US. If you just need to travel to the US urgently, that's an [expedited appointment](https://www.immihelp.com/expedited-appointments-for-usa-visa/).

Comment: You might also like to read the answers to this question: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/122503/can-a-syrian-citizen-get-a-us-visa-regarding-the-travel-ban

Comment: If your application is still in administrative processing there is probably nothing you can do to expedite it. But seven months is kind of ridiculous. Check your status in CEAC and contact the consulate.

Answer (score 4):

Advance Parole is for people with certain pending applications in the US like Adjustment of Status or asylum, or certain statuses that cannot re-enter the US, like TPS, to leave the US and return to the US to resume the pending application or status. It doesn't apply to your situation.

You might be able to get [humanitarian parole](https://www.uscis.gov/humanitarian/humanitarian-or-significant-public-benefit-parole-individuals-outside-united-states), which is for someone outside the US who can't get a visa.

Another option might be to contact the congressman or senator of your relative's district, and see if they can get your visa application expedited.

Comment: I meant humanitarian parole, since I'm outside of the US. I wasn't aware that there is a difference between advance parole and humanitarian parole, since form I-131 is used for both of these. I read the related thread that DJClayworth posted, but that doesn't mention humanitarian parole, only advance parole. Do you think that a German-Syrian dual citizen can get humanitarian parole?

Comment: @123Frage the answer already says that you might be able to get humanitarian parole.  Perhaps what you really want to know is the conditions for granting it, so you can consider whether your circumstances might meet those conditions, or the likelihood that they do.  It would probably be best to ask a new question about that.

Answer (score -1):

If you have a German passport than you should be fine to visit the USA without any issues as "Dual nationals traveling on a non-banned passport" are exempt from the ban

Comment: This is true, but such a person needs to get a visa to enter the USA because people with dual citizenship of a visa waiver program country and Syria are ineligible for the visa waiver program.  The question here arises because the visa application has been pending for seven months.  Therefore, the fact that the ban does not apply to this traveler is not particularly relevant.